# GoToTraining API rejecting json?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, api

OK, I'm using the GoToTraining API to try to create a new Training. The [docs](https://goto-developer.logmeininc.com/content/gototraining-api-reference) say to "post" JSON to the endpoint.

So I have my array of data in PHP (this is a WordPress site, and here I'm grabbing stuff from Advanced Custom Fields data)

```
$my_data_array = array(
    'name' => get_the_title( $_POST['acf']['field_5ab508b853122'] ),
    'description' => $_POST['acf']['field_5ab50b2406457'],
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
    'times' => array(
        array(
            'startDate' => date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $_POST['acf']['field_5ab50908347ef'] ) ) . 'T' . $_POST['acf']['field_5ab50bc6af8df'] . 'Z',
            'endDate' => date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $_POST['acf']['field_5ab50908347ef'] ) ) . 'T' . $_POST['acf']['field_5abbd96c6ff8d'] . 'Z',
        ),
    ),
    'registrationSettings' => array(
        'disableConfirmationEmail' => false,
        'disableWebRegistration' => true,
    )
);
```

and then I'm just doing:

```
$payload = json_encode( $my_data_array )
```

to create the payload, which looks like this, if I print_r the value of $payload:

```
{"name":"Today’s Class","description":"We can add some default content here","timeZone":"America\/Los_Angeles","times":[{"startDate":"2018-04-24T06:00:00Z","endDate":"2018-04-24T09:00:00Z"}],"registrationSettings":{"disableConfirmationEmail":false,"disableWebRegistration":true}}
```

If I make the curl request, posting $payload, I get back:

```
Array
(
[errorCode] => InternalError
[description] => We have encountered an internal error. The request may 
be retried, but it may have the same result.
[incident] => 5102160953111715072
)
```

Could be lots of things, right? But here is thing that's driving me crazy:

If cut and paste that dumped value of $payload above into the "body" field in the sandbox thing on the API reference page (see the link above), it works fine and I get an ID for the new Training back as the response.

Moreover, if I cut and paste that same string and just hardcode it as a string value of my $payload variable in my script (using the exact same code for the curl stuff) -- only difference being I'm hardcoding the value of $payload, like this

```
$payload = '{"name":"Today’s Class","description":"We can add some default content here","timeZone":"America\/Los_Angeles","times":[{"startDate":"2018-04-24T06:00:00Z","endDate":"2018-04-24T09:00:00Z"}],"registrationSettings":{"disableConfirmationEmail":false,"disableWebRegistration":true}}';
```

... and make the request that way, it also works and gives me a successful response!

```
    protected function make_request( $url, $method, $fields ) {

//      $payload = json_encode( $fields );
        $payload = '{"name":"Getting to Know Today’s Electric Utility Industry","description":"We can add some default content here","timeZone":"America\/Los_Angeles","times":[{"startDate":"2018-04-24T06:00:00Z","endDate":"2018-04-24T09:00:00Z"}],"registrationSettings":{"disableConfirmationEmail":false,"disableWebRegistration":true}}';

    $http_headers = array(
        'Accept: application/json',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: OAuth oauth_token=' . $this->access_token,
    );

    $ch = curl_init();

    if ( 'post' == $method ) {

        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );          
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload ); // define what you want to post
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true ); // return the output in string format        
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_headers );
    }

    $response = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch ); // close curl handle

    return $response;
}
```

But what's assigned to $payload here is exactly the same thing I'm getting if I print_r what json_encode() returns. Whaa??

I do notice, if I run

```
mb_detect_encoding( $payload );
```

I get 'ASCII' from the json_encode version and I get 'UTF-8' on the version where I hardcode the string as the value of the variable. Would that make any difference?

Am I missing something simple? Anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong here? Been beating my head against the wall for too many hours.

Answer (score 0):

So for posterity: Turns out that apostrophe in the name of the Training was causing GTT to choke on the data getting sent over. But it had something to do with the get_the_title() function, which handles apostrophes and quotes differently than just grabbing the value from $post->post_title. When I changed the code that was assembling the data for the API call to $post->post_title instead of get_the_title(), it worked.